# Does impala support database cursors?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cursor, impala

I' trying to implement server-side paging. Database cursor looks like a good approach for this. Does Impala supports [database cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) like relational databases? The documentation does not explicitly mention that it does or does not.

Comment: there is no concept of cursors in Impala.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Thanks! Any document/resource to back this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_offset.html) is the official recommendation of doing paging in impala. Short answer : no cursor support. And there isn't a cursor feature in the near dev roadmap either.